# Hide Referer (PHP, or HTML, or JS Doesn't matter)

Tags: php, javascript, html, referrer

I'm using something like this

mysite.com/out.php?url=outurl.com

I'm just using a simple redirect, but I'm just wondering how I can hide the referrer.

Thanks!

edit: I ended up doing a double meta refresh

Comment: Use meta refresh tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The referrer is attached by the user's browser, not by your server, it's up to them to include it or not

Comment: [This firefox extension can remove referrer from all requests](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/referrer-control/?src=hp-dl-upandcoming)

Answer (score 1):

If by hide you mean to remove it from the address bar than you could use a POST request instead of GET or a custom HTTP header. As a third option you could use a GET request but encrypt the data. Also I suppose you are talking about some custom referrer and not the standard [HTTP referrer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer) which might be sent by the user agent.

Answer (score 1):

If you're really serious about hiding the referrer from downsteam sites, you have options...

For example you could try the service

http://referer.us/

which offers rediction (i.e. all referrals appear to come from instead of you).

Depending on your goals, you could easily implement a similar service yourself, either at your own domain (e.g. "/generic-referer.html" if you don't want people seeing the deep-linked page from which a visitor is coming) or a new domain that you control.

Comment: It actually hides refereres for P3P-enabled browsers.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can hide your referrer :
Newer browsers now support this properly anyway, with a meta tag. You can add:

For that page which you want to hide referrer.

I think it will help :-)