# Is it possible to remove the referrer in PHP before redirected?

Tags: php, referrer

But since the browser is the only thing that manages the referrer, however I was thinking about a script that removes the referrer before they are redirected to the link they want to go to.

For example,

> http://mywebsite.com/url.php?u=http://www.stackoverflow.com

Where **url.php** could remove the referrer and then redirect. Is it possible to do this in any way?

Comment: Why would you want to do this, other than for nefarious purposes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide Referer (PHP, or HTML, or JS Doesn't matter)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705820/hide-referer-php-or-html-or-js-doesnt-matter)

Comment: It would be easier if you clearly stated what your intentions are.

Comment: "It would be easier if you clearly stated what your intentions are." year, right... what kind of comment is that? you don't need to answer if you don't want to. i think he wants to hide a referrer - what do you think?

Comment: There are valid reasons. For example, if you are running marketing campaigns and want to hide the referrer info in order to protect your most profitable sources and keywords... just saying, it's not always evil.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If your redirect is an HTTP redirect then, no, you have no control over that.

Nor, frankly, should you. It's the browser's business to form the `REFERER` value, not yours.

Comment: This is false. There are multiple ways of solving this. Answer by Flexo is one way.

Answer (score 13):

You can actually do this in practice if you're running HTTPS on your webserver. You need to force the connection to go via HTTPS as an intermediary so the sequence of redirects would then be:

1. `http://mywebsite.com/url.php?u=http://www.stackoverflow.com` ->
2. `https://mywebsite.com/url.php?u=http://www.stackoverflow.com` ->
3. `http://stackoverflow.com`

[Most browsers don't send a referrer in cases like that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390862/http-referer-lost-using-https) to avoid leaking information that was private and encrypted over insecure channels to unrelated third parties.

---

[Newer browsers](https://caniuse.com/referrer-policy) now [support this properly](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2015/01/21/meta-referrer/) anyway, with a meta tag. You can add:

```
<meta name="referrer" content="never">
```

Generally though you should be setting this option on *all* your pages anyway, so both client and server side redirection would be fine.

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The referer comes from the browser, which you already indicated you understand.

This would be simple enough for you to write a quick test.

Theoretically if you are redirecting to a script that then redirects again, the referer is going to be the redirector script and not the original script.

If you're asking if your script can redirect "invisibly" -- then no, that is outside of the script's control.

Answer (score 0):

Send a user to an HTML page that containing META refresh tag

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http:/redirect.com">
```

Answer (score -8):

try this code:

```
$url = 'your target';
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header( "Location: $url" );
```

Comment: Add some more description of the solution. Please refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer